# Read data from clients machine and save it to database without needing to save the file or upload it to the server

Tags: c#

I have a application where user can save customer location one by one. But if customer has many locations then entering it one by one will take lot of time. So i need a mechanism where user can do a bulk import, meaning they can save all the locations in csv or excel file, and all I need to do is read all the row one by one and save it to the database without needing to save the actual file or upload file to the server.

I am looking for a solution where I can read csv file in memory and usually file size will be less than 5MB.

Currently its working when I do that from my own machine (because I have hard  coded the file path) but it will not work when server and client is on different machine.

This is what i use to parse the csv

```
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\temp\docs\Location.csv"))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                parser.ReadLine();

                var row= new ImportLocationModel();

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    row=ImportLocationModel.FromFields(parser.ReadFields();                  
              clientFindProviderApi.InsertUpdateCustomerListLocation1(list); // saving location in database. 
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, my question is how to read data from client machine (csv, excel) in memory without needing to save the client file in server. And usually client file size is less than 5 mb.

Comment: You need to browse to the file first using a "file" control, then post the file and read the byte array from the posted file into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data to a server without Uploading it is impossible. You can maybe prevent the need to store the Data on the Disk. Just cache into in a MemoryStream, wich will then be collected like all other unused managed Memory.

However it is unclear if that is what you relly need/want. It sounds more like you need/should use a Distributed Database. Once you have a mirror/caching DB in the Client, synching it with the Master on the Server (or vice versa) becomse a DMBS thing.

You should not be asuming anything about the Filesize. "The Developers of Foolproof Systems underestimate the ingenuity of the fools." Asume that some user will create a file/data to synch in the 100 MiB Size. Also asume that your client might be a Mobile Phone wich has a abysmal internet connection at that moment.  So you should move the Synch to a Asynchronous task one way or the other.